# Xcode hang with lots of console messages: "Adding <filename> to localisation file set"

Tags: xcode, localization, console, freeze

Xcode is hanging at various places, at start up, when saving, and during general use.  The beachball appears and when I check out Console.app I am seeing lots of log-lines reading "Adding *filename* to localisation file set" where *filename* is the path to *.string files included in the project.  In my particular project I am using the GoogleMaps for iOS SDK and this has lots of *.string files, so my assumption is that the sheer volume of 'adding' is creating the hang.  What I would like to know is why are these files being added?  Running the same project in Xcode on a different machine doesn't yield these log-lines.

Comment: "When I check out the console..." - is that Xcode's console, or Console.app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but the issue has gone away upon a complete removal of Xcode (4.6.3) from my Mac OSX 10.8.4 system, followed by a re-install.